# minimum using Newton method (matlab)

Tags: optimization, matlab, newton-raphson

I am given this function: $$f(x,y)=\frac { 1 }{ 2 } { (x-1) }^{ 2 }+\frac { 1 }{ 2 } { (10(y−{ x }^{ 2 })) }^{ 2 }+\frac { 1 }{ 2 } { y }^{ 2 }$$ and I tried to write the code below to find the minimum using Newton method, but it doesn't seem to work. I think it can not assign the new value of variables but I don't know why.

syms a;

syms b;

g=gradient(vrosenbrock(a,b));

x=-1;

y=-1;

z=0;

i=1;

H=hessian(vrosenbrock(a,b));

while norm(subs(g,[a,b],[x,y])) > 10e-3

```
z=[x,y]-((subs(inv(H),[a,b],[x,y]))*((subs(g,[a,b],[x,y])))).' ;
x=z(1); y=z(2);
i=i+1;
```

end

[x y]

And as function I've saved this already:

function z = vrosenbrock(x,y)

FUN = 1;

if  FUN == 1

```
z = 0.5*(10*(y - x.^2)).^2 + 0.5*(1-x).^2 + 0.5*y.^2;
```

elseif  FUN == 2

```
z = (10*(y - x.^2)).^2 + (1-x).^2;
```

end

end

Comment: Are you looking for someone to debug your code???

Comment: Tell me if I am wrong but I have some doubt about the end of your iteration step with a point followed by a quote sign. Is the point useful ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I did that to make the vector transpose(if I understood you right)...when I delete it, it can't multiplicate the matrix with the vector. Is there anything else you notice?

Comment: Don't delete the quote sign which indeed is there for transposing; My concern was about the accompanying point.

Comment: @JeanMarie ah but still it gives the same result

Comment: Can you say what happens ? No convergence ? That wouldn't be surprizing  with the "banana shape' of Rosenbrock ....

Comment: @JeanMarie after 10 iterations it gives an unbelievably big point which can never be a minimizer

Comment: Even if your code is "correct", Newton's method without line search, trust region, or some other protection, is garbage, and can diverge, even on convex problems.

Comment: @Moo you must have entered a different function. Your min value of f  and optimal x and y don't match up with the function (Fun = 1) provided. For the function provided, globally optimal x = 0.5911, y = 0.3459, min value of f  = 0.1440. I am not aware of any other local optima, but given that f is not everywhere convex, I am not sure there are not any others.